# Regex Pattern for Decimals or Fraction

Tags: c#, regex

I am awful with Regex patterns. I am trying to validate input (with C#) in the form of a whole number (1234), decimal (1234.50), or fraction (1234 1/2). I am currently using this pattern

> [^0-9.]+

which only handles whole numbers and decimals. Is there a way I can extend this to handle fractions as well?

Comment: Are you actually planning on parsing the input to `int` or `decimal`? Or is this stored/utilized as a string?

Comment: I have a WPF converter that takes the fraction text and converts it to a decimal for me. So to answer your question -- decimal

Comment: I've added an answer that avoids Regex if you're interested, but it assumes you're converting the fraction to decimal yourself. I don't know why you need the converter (it's a simple operation?) but if you need to use it you're probably better off using Regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regex like this:

```
^\(\d+(?:\.?\d*|\s\d+\/\d+)\)$
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/nK9eB0/1)**

If you don't want to include the parentheses you can use

```
^\d+(?:\.?\d*|\s\d+\/\d+)$
```

You can see easily both decimal/fraction patterns:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: That diagram is awesome!  Did you create that by hand or is there a tool that can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Regex is fine if you're just looking to validate the string and store the input as a `string`. However, if you're going to be doing any operations on the numerical value, you're better off just trying to parse the value straight-away.

```
string input = "1234 1/2";
decimal? inputAsDec = null;
decimal? fractionAsDec = null;
var wholeAndFraction = input.Split(' ');

if (wholeAndFraction.Count == 2 && input.Contains('/'))
{
    var fraction = wholeAndFraction[1].Split('/');
    decimal? numerator = null;
    decimal? denominator = null;

    if (decimal.TryParse(fraction[0], out numerator) && decimal.TryParse(fraction[1], out denominator))
    {
        fractionAsDec = numerator / denominator;
    }
}

if (decimal.TryParse(wholeAndFraction[0], out inputAsDec))
{
    if (fractionAsDec != null)
    {
        inputAsDec += fractionAsDec;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
\d*(?:\s+\d+/\d+|\.\d+)?
```